# DOB field in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I want to calculate age and from DOB field. But in my code I am hard coding it. But need to do dynamically like today - DOB. Similarly I also want to calculate duration from start_date. My data frame looks like -

```
id                        dob                           start_date
77                     30/09/1990                     2019-04-13 15:27:22
65                     15/12/1988                     2018-12-26 23:28:12
3                      08/12/2000                     2018-12-26 23:28:17
```

I have so far - For age calculation

```
df= df.withColumn('dob',to_date(unix_timestamp(F.col('dob'),'dd/MM/yyyy').cast("timestamp")))
end_date = '3/09/2019'
end_date = pd.to_datetime(end_date, format="%d/%m/%Y")
df= df.withColumn('end_date',F.unix_timestamp(F.lit(end_date),'dd/mm/yyyy').cast("timestamp"))
df = df.withColumn('age', (F.datediff(F.col('end_date'), F.col('dob')))/365)
df= df.withColumn("age", func.round(df["age"], 0))

For duration calculation - 

end_date_1 = '2019-09-30'
end_date_1 = pd.to_datetime(end_date_1, format="%Y-%m-%d")
df= df.withColumn('end_date_1',F.unix_timestamp(F.lit(end_date_1),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').cast("timestamp"))
df= df.withColumn('duration', (F.datediff(F.col('end_date_1'), F.col('created_at'))))
```

In the above two codes I have hard code two values. One is end_date = '2019-09-30' and other is end_date_1 = '2019-09-30'. But want to do this based on todays() date. How to do it in pyspark?

Comment: why not use the builtin function: `current_date()`  http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.current_date

Answer (score 0):

You can use date.today() to get today's date as you are using python with spark.
More information about the desired date format can be found here [official python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)

Comment: is there any packages need to install?Actually got an error - NameError: name 'date' is not defined...although install two pck...import datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, unix_timestamp, to_date

Comment: @PallaviVerma Yes, you have to add import for datetime:
`from datetime import date`, please refer to documentation in the [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) provided.

Comment: Already added from datetime import date...but still getting error - 'ValueError: time data datetime.date(2019, 10, 4) does not match format '%d/%m/%Y' (match)'
my full code is - 
df1 = df1.withColumn('dob',to_date(unix_timestamp(F.col('dob'),'dd/MM/yyyy').cast("timestamp")))
end_date = date.today()
end_date = pd.to_datetime(end_date, format="%d/%m/%Y")
df1 = df1.withColumn('end_date',F.unix_timestamp(F.lit(end_date),'dd/mm/yyyy').cast("timestamp")) df1= df1.withColumn('age', (F.datediff(F.col('end_date'), F.col('dob')))/365) df1 = df1.withColumn("age", func.round(df1["age"], 0))

Comment: ValueError: time data datetime.date(**2019, 10, 4**) does not match format '**%d/%m/%Y**' 

The error message clearly states the format of the date provided is not matching

Comment: @PallaviVerma The format of date in your dataframe doesn't match the default date format of python.
You can use `date.today().strftime("%d/%m/%y")` for modifying format.